# Skype4Py line break

Tags: python, skype, nagios

I try to use **Skype4Py** for **Nagios** notifications. I already can send messages from command-line. Now I try to insert line-break character (carriage return) into body of message. I use the following scripts to send notifications:
 **/usr/local/nagios/sbin/skype_alert.sh** my_skype_login "RECOVERY\n" "Host: nagios-test\r" "Service: PING" "Info: PING OK 1.22ms":

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
PT=`which python`
SKYPE_LOGIN=$1
SKYPE_MESSAGE="${@:2}"
$PT /usr/local/nagios/sbin/skype_alert.py $SKYPE_LOGIN "$SKYPE_MESSAGE"
```

/usr/local/nagios/sbin/skype_alert.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Skype4Py
import sys
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()
user = sys.argv[1]
msg=' '.join(sys.argv[2:]) 
skype.SendMessage(user, msg)
```

Can somebody tell me how to insert line breaks (carriage return) in message? I tried `\n` `\r` and so on..

Comment: UPDATE: Here is solution: http://python.su/forum/topic/29784/?page=1#post-161885

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: Here is solution: 
http://python.su/forum/topic/29784/?page=1#post-161885 
Hope it help somebody)

Comment: Why don't you provide the solution on this website instead of forcing people to view a third-party website?